# silverstripe how to create an holder/page without action

Tags: php, silverstripe

I trying to create a holder/page in silverstripe that list no action only ID, just like the blog pages, if there is no ID (mydomain.com/programs/) than show a list of all the programs if there is an ID (mydomain.com/programs/spinning-with-chris/) than I want a details page with the program.

Does anybody have an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you haven't defined a custom URL handler in your controller, the default is this:

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' => 'handleAction',
);
```

This means that your route will be `routetocontroller/action` then anything after that will be optional ([more info](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/controllers/routing/#url-patterns)). The first part of the route would be defined in your YAML configuration, e.g.:

```
Director:
  rules:
    routetocontroller: YourControllerName
```

Therefore your controller needs to expose an index action:

```
private static $allowed_actions = array('index');

public function index(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
{
    // Handle an ID passed
    if ($id = $this->urlParams['ID']) {
        return $this->doSomethingWithYourId($id);
    }

    // Otherwise, show all of your data
    return $this->renderWith(array('YourTemplateName', array(
        'YourDataList' => YourModel::get()
    ));
}
```

And you can loop and display then in `YourTemplateName.ss`:

```
<% loop $YourDataList %>
    <li><a href="$Link">$Title</a></li>
<% end_loop %>
```

These are only starting point examples, you'll need to adjust it to suit your needs of course.

Comment: Great, this is working the only problem I have it that it only renders the page content, not the framework.
ProgramSchedulePage_Controller extends Page_Controller but it not picking up the page template, any idea’s how to do that or do I have to make the “ProgramSchedulePage” template a full page template?

Comment: @Mi32dogs perhaps your template is `templates/ProgramSchedulePage.ss` - this will override the Page template entirely. You should store it as `templates/Layout/ProgramSchedulePage.ss` instead so it's only covering the content

Comment: I did have it in the layout folder but it was still overriding the page template, I also lost all the page data itself. I got it working by first getting the page data $dObj = Page::get()->byID('8'); and then render it with both templates return $this->customise($dObj)->renderWith(array('ProgramSchedulePage', 'page')); it is not the best solution but it is working